# DocuSignAPI REST - Why won't my OAuth request go through?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm attempting to use the DocuSign REST API and create an OAuth request to execute Send of Behalf of (SOBO). Although I can't complete the first task, it's giving me back a Bad Request. What am I doing wrong?

**Request with Headers:**

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/oauth2/token

Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: {length of body}
```

**Request Body**

```
<OAuthTokenRequest>
  <grant_type>password</grant_type>
  <client_id>{IntegratorKey}</client_id>
  <username>test@email.com</username>
  <password>{Password}</password>
  <scope>api</scope>
</OAuthTokenRequest>
```

**Response with Error:**

```
400 Bad Request 

<oauthErr xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <error>invalid_request</error>
  <error_description>An OAuth2 error occurred:</error_description>
</oauthErr>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although most of the DocuSign REST API accepts XML formatting, OAuth requests must be made in *x-www-form-urlencoded*.

Change your request to the following:

**Request with Headers:**

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/oauth2/token

Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: {length of body}
```

**Request Body:**

```
grant_type=password&client_id={IntegratorKey}&username=test@email.com&password={Password}&scope=api
```

**Sample Response:**

```
200 OK

<oauthAccess xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <access_token>{Access Token}</access_token>
  <scope>api</scope>
  <token_type>bearer</token_type>
</oauthAccess>
```

**[More information can be obtained in this documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo).**